# How can I render a website as an image from the shell?

Tags: html, linux, terminal, png

Looking to say "http://example.com/index.html -o website.png"

Is there an existing program to do this? I'm ok with doing html to png. Is there a program for that?

Comment: Do you want webpage screenshots?

Comment: @PENDO yes screenshots. @Mohamed Meligy looking to script something in the shell.

Comment: If you want to "script something in the shell" then you need a *command-line* application to do it, and @Mohamed Meligy's comment still applies.

Comment: I think you need a [html to pdf and image converter](http://www.hiqpdf.com).

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR; Try [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org)

**Original Answer:** (2011 -- before question tags added)

Check the answer to this question. It seems the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux

If it's on Windows, check also:

- http://www.labnol.org/software/automated-screenshots-of-websites-from-command-line/4786/
- http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html

**Updated Answer:**

A few other console / terminal based tools that can convert HTML to images.

- [<strike>phantomjs.org</strike>](http://phantomjs.org/) (**Update:** No longer maintaned)
- [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) (look for wkhtmltoimage)

They are both cross OS, free, and very popular.

Comment: phantom is no longer maintained, I think wkhtmltoimage is the best solution. It might be good to revise this answer to make wkhtmltoimage more prominent.

Comment: Good point. Done.

Answer (score 0):

[quick search turns up this program](http://www.webscreencapture.com/)

**Main features**

- Create full size screenshots of website pages.
- Supports JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP image formats.
- Supports command line usage.
- Supports batch convert with command line.
- Simple, very fast and easy-to-use.
- Freeware, not paid for use.

Answer (score 0):

While it is no direct solution, the [browsershots project](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/) is open source and basically provides what is requested here.

Answer (score 0):

I use CutyCapt, https://www.xmodulo.com/convert-html-web-page-png-image-linux.html

However, I'm also on Linux.  But it answered for me exactly what the OP asked for.